# Simulate CompletionException in a test

Tags: java, exception, mockito, completable-future

I've got a class `HttpClient` that has a function that returns `CompletableFuture`:

```
public class HttpClient {

  public static CompletableFuture<int> getSize() {
      CompletableFuture<int> future = ClientHelper.getResults()
                 .thenApply((searchResults) -> {
                    return searchResults.size();
                });

      return future;
   }
}
```

Then another function calls this function:

```
public class Caller {

   public static void caller() throws Exception {
       // some other code than can throw an exception
       HttpClient.getSize()
       .thenApply((count) -> {
          System.out.println(count);
          return count;
       })
       .exceptionally(ex -> {
          System.out.println("Whoops! Something happened....");
       });
   }
}
```

Now, I want to write a test to simulates that `ClientHelper.getResults` **fails**, so for that I wrote this:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    HttpClient mockClient = mock(HttpClient.class);

    try {
        Mockito.doThrow(new CompletionException(new Exception("HTTP call failed")))
                .when(mockClient)
                .getSize();

        Caller.caller();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail("Caller should not have thrown an exception!");
    }
}
```

This test fails. The code within `exceptionally` never gets executed. However, if I run the source code normally and the HTTP call does fail, it goes to the `exceptionally` block just fine.

**How must I write the test so that the `exceptionally` code is executed?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I got this to work by doing this in the test:

```
CompletableFuture<Long> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
future.completeExceptionally(new Exception("HTTP call failed!"));

Mockito.when(mockClient.getSize())
        .thenReturn(future);
```

Not sure if this is the best way though.

Comment: I think this is the best way: CompletableFuture is a widely-used and well-tested library, so you can rely on it for testing your code instead of trying to replicate its behavior using Mockito. (Of course, Mockito is a decent way to supply the Future in your system-under-test's dependency that you mock.)